# How manage with Java a non AWS , Google or IBM Object Storage

Tags: java, object-storage

I'm trying to manage my ProfitBricks S3 Object Storage Bucket using java, I want to do the basics (add, remove, list) operations but all I have found on internet is to connect to a AWS, Google or IBM Object Storage.

I have tried to use one implementation of those but I don't find how to provide my provider Endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using the jets3t library and I have set the endpoint property using a Jets3tProperties object.

```
    Jets3tProperties props = new Jets3tProperties();
    props.setProperty("s3service.disable-dns-buckets", String.valueOf(true));
    props.setProperty("s3service.s3-endpoint", PB_ENDPOINT);
    props.setProperty("s3service.s3-endpoint-http-port", PB_ENDPOINT_HTTP_PORT);
    props.setProperty("s3service.s3-endpoint-https-port", PB_ENDPOINT_HTTPS_PORT);
    props.setProperty("s3service.https-only", String.valueOf(false));
    AWSCredentials creds = new AWSCredentials(PB_ACCESS_KEY, PB_SECRET_KEY);
    RestS3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(creds, null, null, props);
```

And then with the **s3Service** object I was able to manage my ProfitBricks S3 Object Storage Bucket using java.